# How to avoid IE page freezing

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have a table which contains at least 15K rows. Each table row has a column which contains two radio buttons (Replace and Keep options). In column header the two radio buttons offer the posibility to 'replace all' or 'keep all'. 
When the user choose 'replace all' or 'keep all' the browser is freezing and a litle popup appers which says "server name is not responding". If I wait for 5 minutes the browser starts to work again. This issue happens in IE only.

See below the event function for radio buttons 'replace all' and 'keep all'

```
function Specht_Confirm_All(opt) {
    jQuery("tbody.scrollContent input[type='radio'][id ^='rb_" + opt + "']").prop("checked", true);
}
```

I suppose that the problem apperas because every time I tick a radio button  (programatically) the browser starts to relayout the page, which takes a cosiderable amount of time.

What should I do to force `IE` to have the same behavior as `Google Chrome`?

Comment: I think your design needs some re-work. Why would you ever try to display 15k rows of data at one time? There is something called pagination.

Comment: these are client's requirements. Alose the clients said that the application should work in both `IE 11` and `Google Chrome`

Comment: To add to Ryan's comment, I would make your table pagable and use AJAX calls to return a smaller set of those 15k lines.

Comment: What exactly are your client's requirements? Is it "I want to see all 15,000 lines at the exact same time", or is it "I want access to all 15,000 lines". Two different stories.

Comment: Check out jQuery Datatables using AJAX:https://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html

Comment: @RyanC He wants to be able to see all without pagination and chose the option accordingly.

Comment: Than your only option is not a loop, but a series of timeouts to keep browser from freezing.

Comment: @epascarello I made a test, I ticked the first 100 items only, but still takes a lot of time (around 10 seconds)

Comment: More context would be helpful. Are you using datatables?

Comment: @JayJordan No. The table is generated on server and  I use `jQuery` to check the radio buttons.

Comment: And the table is rendering each time?

Comment: @JayJordan The table is redered just when the page is served. Every time a tick a radio button I do my work using only javascript/JQuery, so the answer is no, just once

Comment: What is causing this? "I suppose that the problem apperas because every time I tick a radio button (programatically) the browser starts to relayout the page, which takes a cosiderable amount of time."

Comment: I mean that every time the page is changed (via javascript) the browser analyses and makes the coresponding changes. For a better explanation see the following link http://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170788/discussion-between-jay-jordan-and-roroinpho21).